# Configure a container for using it with juju

Tags: juju, cloud, lxc

Is there a way to use `juju` o LXC containers that have not been created by `juju bootstrap`? The only configuration options for `local` containers are the `root-dir` and the `admin-secret`, which I understand some service within the container should be able to receive. Looking at the [original message where this feature was announced](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/juju/2011-October/000847.html) that's probably zookeeper, but still I am not too sure how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the local provider can be found here:
https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/clouds-manual

There are ways, that have not been fully tested, to use manual provisioning to use containers not started by juju, but this is not advised at this time.

Ignore the admin-secret, and this is actually being moved out of the environments.yaml file.  You only need it to log into the juju-gui.  Other than that it is used by the internal system.

Zookeeper is no long used with the newer versions of juju (> 1.0).

The root-dir is useful if you are using an encrypted home dir, or you just want the log files and mongo database stored elsewhere.